# Calculating Napier constant (e) using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am attempting to approximate the value of e (~2.7)

Defined by this, for each nth term

[image: defined by this, for each nth term]

using a recursive function in python.

So far I have gotten this,

```
def NapierConstant(runs):
    return 2 + 1/contfrac(1, 2, runs)

def contfrac(v1, v2, limit):
    if v1 == limit:
        return (v1/v2)
    else:
        return v1+(v1/contfrac(v1+1, v2+1, limit))

print(NapierConstant(2))
```

this should output 2.72727 here, but instead I get 2.4, and the error margin get's worse for each following step. I have googled, and I can't manage to figure out how to set up the function recursively so that it outputs the expected values.

Comment: From the code, I don't understand what's your purpose, maybe more info you could provide to let us know better. You could try the online visualization execution on [http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html)

Comment: I'm trying to create the function of e ~ 2+ 1/(1+ 1/(2+ 2/(3+ 3/...))) I hope that makes sense, don't know how to format it better. This is a sample for a competition, and I cannot for the life of me remember how to set up recursive functions properly

Comment: Added an image that hopefully clarifies what I am trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def get_e(lim):
    return 2 + 1/r(1, lim)

def r(v1, lim):
    if v1 == lim:
        return v1 + v1/(v1+1)
    else:
        return v1 + v1/(r(v1+1, lim))
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much, I didn't even realise I needed that v1 in the base case